# How to use ag-grid checkbox with angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

[image]

How to bind the checkbox value with event.and how to access the curresponding data?

**home.ts**

```
 columns = [
 {
  field: 'reportingLocation',
  headerName: 'Reporting Location '
 },
 {
  field: 'country',
  headerName: 'Country Name'
 },
 {
  field: 'DEL',
  headerName: 'DEL',
  editable:true,
  headerCheckboxSelection: true,
  headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
  checkboxSelection: true
 } ];
```

And i have one function to get the rows with `DEL=TRUE`

```
 deleteLocations(e) {
console.log(this.list);
e.preventDefault();
this.list
.filter((item: any) => {
  return !!item.DEL;
})
.map(item => {
  this.store.dispatch(new

 LocationAndResponsibilityActions.OnLocationDelete(item.location_Id));
  });  }
```

I could not access the `DEL` Value,What is the proper way to use aggrid checkbox selection?

Answer (score 0):

ag-grid has a number of [selection events](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#selection), but it sounds like `(rowSelected)` may be what you are looking for. It passes an object back as a param which contains the row data as well as some other useful properties.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EuS2ywgMJLu4NlXrq5xU?p=preview)